# A way to programatically modify packets (Ethernet, IP, Application) on the fly

Tags: security, network-protocols

I need to prepare an application (for demonstration/steganography purposes) that would be able to change values of header fields of layer 2/3/4/7 PDUs (for example Ethernet, IP, UDP and HTTP). Perfectly, it would do so on the fly, running on a node serving as a router (layer 3 and up) or a bridge (layer 2). So far I have only found software like Ettercap (which is L2-only) and libnetfilter_queue library (that AFAIR allows me to modify only IP PDUs).

I'm looking for a library/set of libraries that would allow me to do in the simplest manner possible under Linux/Windows using Java, C#, C or C++. I'll be grateful for any suggestions on where I should direct my attention.

Comment: If you capture packets on layer 2, you do the rest yourself, i.e. you analyze packets if they contain TCP or UDP, and if it's TCP, then if it's some upper-level protocol traffic. This is how packet capturing applications work. I doubt that you will find a ready to use library that will do all of analysis work for you.

Comment: In the end, I used libnetfilter_queue to modify IP packets in C++, with Qt to build GUI. After some initial problems setting up packet modification, it worked beautifully. Thanks for support!